# How to use Future from Async function?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to get the value from an Async function that returns an integer which is then used to set the color of a widget in my UI.

Async function:

```dart
// Returns a future<int> instead of an int due to async
Future<int> getLikeStatus(String name) async {
  int likeStatus =
      await getLikeStatusFromPostLikes(name); // this returns an int
  return likeStatus;
}
```

Post Function:

```
 Future <List<dynamic>> fetchData() async {
  // Some code to make GET request to private server with data and push as posts
  final response = await posts.get();
  final result = response.map((m) => Post.fromJson(m)).toList();

  return result;
}
```

Downstream usage  - uses the above `post` function:

```dart
// snapshot is populated by post future in FutureBuilder
child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
              future: post,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) { 
                   ...
                   Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: <Widget>[
                         InkWell(
                            child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
                            color: getLikeStatus(snapshot.data[index].name) == 1
                ? Colors.green
                : Colors.blue) // cannot use future here
                      ),
  ],
);
```

How can I return the `likeStatus` variable to use for the `color` attribute in my widget?

EDIT: Added code showing use of `FutureBuilder`

Comment: use FutureBuilder (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget

Comment: @Black what did you assign to `post` variable?

Comment: @CrazyLazyCat made edit

Comment: @Black but you can still use the solution that creativecreatorormaybenot gave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use nested `FutureBuilder` then you can make them as single future function(`fetchAll`) like this,

```
post = fetchAll();

....

Future<Map<Post, int>> fetchAll() async {
  final posts = await fetchData();
  final result = <Post, int>{};
  for(final x in posts){
    final status = await getLikeStatus(x.name);
    result[x] = status;
  }
  return result;
}

Future <List<Post>> fetchData() async {
  // Some code to make GET request to private server with data and push as posts
  final response = await posts.get();
  final result = response.map((m) => Post.fromJson(m)).toList();
  return result;
}

// Returns a future<int> instead of an int due to async
Future<int> getLikeStatus(String name) async {
  int likeStatus =
  await getLikeStatusFromPostLikes(name); // this returns an int
  return likeStatus;
}

...

    child: FutureBuilder<Map<Post, int>>(
      future: post,  //TODO: `fetchAll` instead of `fetchData`
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          //Since snapshot is a map you can get `Post` data using `snapshot.data.entries.elementAt(index)`
          ...
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              InkWell(
                  child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
                      color: snapshot.data.entries.elementAt(index).value
                          ? Colors.green
                          : Colors.blue) // cannot use future here
              ),
            ],
          ),
          //...
        }
      },
    ),
```

Above the fetch status request send one after another. So it may take long if the name list is large. You can make it parallel like this,

```
Future<Map<Post, int>> fetchAll() async {
  final posts = await fetchData();
  final result = <Post, int>{};
  final statusList =
      await Future.wait<int>(posts.map((x) => getLikeStatus(x.name)));
  for (int i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    result[posts[i]] = statusList[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know multiple futures could be added into one super future. Thank you

Comment: @Black Don't use `.forEach` in `fetchAll` method. I updated the code

Comment: Changed this, optimisation makes a lot of sense. Thank you